# Suppressing carrier using attenuator and phase shifter

Tags: rf

In the article shown in the link, we have a circuit shown below.
The blue arrow is the return signal from the cavity resonator where the main carrier is at 10 GHz. The red signal which is 10 GHz from YIG source.

I can't understand how can we suppress the 10 GHz carrier. I know that we can do 180 degree phase (minus) mathematically. But in practice how we use test equipment to get the complex value of the returned signal and cancel the carrier?

What test equipment do we use, how we know that the attenuator and phase shifter values are going to suppress the carrier? How exactly do we suppress the carrier?

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1275129

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to replace the cavity with a matched load so that (ideally) there is no reflected wave, then adjust the amplitude and phase of the cancellation circuitry to null out the leakage through the circulator.

You are trying to measure the phase of the reflection coefficient of the cavity, you are calibrating to remove stray 'reflections' by nulling with an equal amplitude, opposite phase signal.